# Why does cycles render take forever to render?

Tags: animation

I am working on a Minecraft animation and whenever I am using cycles render and whenever I render the scene to check on my lightning, it takes FOREVER to render. It takes 20 minutes just to render ONE scene. If this continues, I'll never finish this animation. I've been looking for answers online but I seem to be the only one with this problem. The weird thing is, I had an older computer that was terrible and I now have a new computer that is really fast. I have never had this problem on my old computer. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at your pfp I can tell you know about Black Plasma Studios since you are using their rig,

also take your time to read all of this since it's kinda long to explain, be patient and read :D (pssss, there's also pictures so it's easier to understand)

on the animation tutorial made by Arbiter617 it's explained how to animate and very little about scene performance, and that's why I am here to help you on making your scene faster in viewport and render!

if you follow these steps you should be good

Step 1: Graphics card

a graphics card is what is going to make your rendering faster, the better the card the faster the render, take in mind that not all graphics cards are the same for blender, the bests to use are the Nvidia TITAN and the 10th series because those are the most supported, other graphics cards such as Nvidia quadro or any AMD graphics card won't work as fast as the ones I mentioned because Blender does not support AMD or profesional graphics cards.

Now, without a graphics card doesn't mean you can't animate, you can also render using a CPU but it might take a little more time, you m ight be thinking: "so without a good graphics card it will take forever?" not necessarily, there is other stuff such as energy consumption, light bounces, resolution, samples, and other important stuff I'll talk about later on

so the first thing we'll do is prepare our graphics card or cpu for rendering,

Go into file > user preferences > system > cycles computer device> and select CUDA, then check the box with your graphics card

[image: User preferences]

[image: System]

Now that we got our graphics card we are ready to go onto the next step and one of the most crucial in our render times

Step 2: Rendering Performance

This is the most important since we'll optimize the final render of the animation with a few tricks, now before you do the changes these settings are the settings I'd recommend for any Minecraft scene but not for photorealistic scenes, we'll be adjusting the samples, light bounces, and rendering style, now what are these things or how do they work? below you can read what they are for and how you can learn how to use them

Samplings: noisy render? make the numbers bigger!

this is a very common issue for new Minecraft animators that their scenes are supper noisy and don't know why, one reason can be that they are not using proper lighting to light up the scene as it should do in the real world, the most common fix is to adjust the lighting or increase the samples but that consumes a lot of render time.

The higher the samples the more little particles will bounce and hit the camera,

now there are people who set a crazy ammount of samples such as 500 for animations and even 30,000 for a single render, it's not necessary to set the samples that high because it would take hours for a single frame, instead we'll use a function called "Denoising", what denoising does is self explanatory lol, it gets rid of the extra noise by blurring the already existing color on the image, for a Minecraft animation with denoising you can use between 50 and 250 samples

[image: Samples]

Trivia!, in the video Animation life 2 part 3, Arbiter617 used only 75 samples plus denoising! so it's not the ammount of samples but good lighting

you can enable Denoising by checking the box on properties > scene > denoising

We now know what is samples now let's learn about...

Light bounces: light goes boing boing!

we know that when light comes in touch with an object it bounces to the camera right?, with light bounces we can adjust the quality of the light bouncing on materials, this list of materials include Diffuse, Glossy, Reflections, and Volume, the default bounce values are set for accurate realistic lighting but since Minecraft animation is not that complex we can go as low as we want!.

[image: Light bounces]

Now you see I market the refractive caustics as red, because we don't need them, those are only use for realistic glass light reflection and that's impossible to see in Minecraft.

we know what samples and light bounces are yay, now for the last thing

Performance: only one simple setting!

It's actually really simple, for CPU's set the tile size to 8, and for GPU's set it to 256, this only affects the tile size of when blender is rendering the image
[image: Oof]

to go to this setting go to Properties > render > performance

take in mind all of these values don't have to be the exact same for all Minecraft scenes but you can use this as a default, if your renders are still slow try using a lower resolution like 1280x720 or lower samples
with all of this you should be good for rendering, I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you! It renders faster now! Thank you!