# How to better optimize Cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, sapling-addon

I have a pretty complex scene made up of 15 sapling trees (which are all duplicates of each other), each with leaves. Obviously this means I have really long render times. While rendering I noticed this "duplicates" data point: [image]
which is always at 0%. How can I make my scene so that I can utilize duplicates to speed up rendering time?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106163/why-does-cycles-render-take-forever-to-render/106169#106169

Comment: Thanks, but that's not my issue. I understand all of that. My question is how can I utilize whatever "duplicates" the arrow I'm pointing to indicates. I assume it would help my rendering time if it was more than 0%. :-)

Comment: if all the trees are the exactly same then you should duplicate them using Alt + D and not Ctrl + D, because Alt + D makes an exact  duplicate without creating more mesh data, if you use Ctrl + D is like you have created another different object